# How do I click on a ListView item using PyWinAuto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to click on an item in a list but continue to get errors. When I click on the item with the mouse the regular way, it loads information about the item that is needed for manipulation.

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import Application, keyboard, mouse
from pywinauto.keyboard import send_keys, KeySequenceError
from pywinauto.controls.common_controls import _listview_item, ListViewWrapper



letter_array = ['P']
path = r"\\10.10.3.106\Production\Embroidery\Embroidery Fonts\Art Deco"
path_to_embrilliance = f"C:\Program Files\BriTon Leap\Embrilliance\Embroidery.exe"

# pywinauto.Application().start(path_to_embrilliance)
# embrilliance = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=path_to_embrilliance)

pywinauto.Application().start(path_to_embrilliance)
embrilliance = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=path_to_embrilliance)
NewWindowEmbrilliance = embrilliance.Window_()

pywinauto.Application().start(r'explorer.exe "{}"'.format(path))
explorer = Application(backend='uia').connect(path='explorer.exe')
NewWindowExplorer = explorer.Window_()
NewWindowExplorer.set_focus()

# for 2 letter configuration //Art Deco
for i in range(len(letter_array)):
    some_letter = letter_array[i]

    file_item = NewWindowExplorer.ItemsView.get_item(
        'Art Deco{0}.dst'.format(some_letter))
    file_item.right_click_input()
    explorer.ContextMenu['Copy'].invoke()

    NewWindowEmbrilliance.set_focus()
    NewWindowEmbrilliance.draw_outline()
    NewWindowEmbrilliance.type_keys(r'^v')

    i += i

NewWindowExplorer.type_keys("%{F4}")

# NewWindowEmbrilliance.print_control_identifiers()

# select the last letter placed



ListViewWrapper.set_focus(self=NewWindowEmbrilliance)
ListViewWrapper.right_click_input()
```

The Art DecoP needs to be clicked to load the position.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `continue to get errors` what errors? Seeing as this isn't going to be reproducible by anyone else unless they have that specific program, we need all the relevant info you possibly have.

Comment: raise AttributeError("Neither GUI element (wrapper) " \
AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'has_focus' were found (typo?)

Comment: It would be much better if you put that info in the question itself, along with the line number that's giving you that error. When you step through the code line-by-line with a debugger, when does that error happen?